# Is there a way I can let W3C conformance checker through my php security?

Tags: php, w3c-validation

I would like to let W3C through my webpage security at the minute I have this for member pages,

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'], $_SESSION['layout'])) {
     header('Location ...............');
     .............
}
```

Whenever I dynamically add the link to my webpages to be able to check it obviously my pages redirect the checker back to the signup page. Is there a way I can tell the request is coming from W3C html5 conformance checker like,

```
if (isset($_POST['W3Cchecker'])) {
     let the script run
}
```

Comment: If it's just a small number of pages to check, why not just paste the code into the validator?

Comment: It isn't a small number it is plus 2000+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not securely, no.

Anything that you use to detect the W3C site could be forged by a malicious user (save possibly for IP address, but you don't want to do that).

You could host/save a second, identical copy of your site (sans whatever content you're trying to protect) and run the validator against that, or you could run your own copy of the validator program, modified to authenticate itself.